# Ubuntu: "Editable Menu Accelerators" (on a per app basis). Where is this option?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, shortcut-keys, gtk

I keep seeing references to a config option calld `Editable Menu Accelerators` or `Editable Menu Shortcut Keys`.
This is exactly what I need, but all the directions I've read about how to find that feature lead me to a dead-end.

I am running with Ubuntu 10.4, and have checked its help file `Desktop User Guide`.
In Section `8.2.1.4. Interface Preferences` it says:

```
"...the Interface tabbed section in the Appearance preference tool  
    to customize the appearance of menus, menubars, and toolbars  
    for applications that are part of GNOME."
```

This `Interface` tab does not exist in Ubuntu 10.4  (... okay, who moved it?! ..  where is i?)
Is this feature still available?
I assume it does exist, and is now accessible some other way... but **how?**

PS: To clarify... I want to modify a menu-item accelerator for a specific app (not a system-wide hot-key)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that GNOME decided to remove the interface tab because ["basically everything there is a user experience design cop-out.  It only belongs in a tweak UI tool."](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=592756) So now the only way to enable that option is hidden deep in the gconf settings.

Launch `gconf-editor` from the terminal or the "Run Application" dialog (`Alt-F2`).

Navigate to `desktop>gnome>interface` and check `can_change_accels`

Or just run this line in a terminal:

```
gconftool --set /desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels --type=bool True
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thanks... gconf-editor suits me fine ;)  ... but I now understand why they removed from general access! It is so damn powerful, its scary.  One mis-typed key while a menu is open changes that item's accelerator key (as intended by this feature)... and it does it wheter you meant to press that key or not. Its hair-trigger nature (where you don't normaally make silent mods) may lead to a few lost toes...  I'll turn it on/off as needed...  Go Linux! ... (I'm below 15 points.. can't mark up your anwer yet_

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in GNOME 3.4 on Precise using either `gconf-editor` or `dconf-editor` (latter case, using the key `/org/gnome/desktop/interface/can-change-accels`).

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail, see [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/136062/permanent-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-for-evince-document-viewer/136112#136112) for Precise, especially the "global menu" part.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this functionality is now in "Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts".

For example, I usually pop in there to clear CTRL-ALT-DEL from the "Log out" option (double click on the entry, then press backspace.

Then hit the "Add" button and create a new entry called "Force Quit" which launches "xkill".  Now double click on that and press CTRL-ALT-DEL.

Now whenever you have a window which isn't responding, just hit CTRL-ALT-DEL and click on the offending window.

Comment: I looked at "Preferences/Keyboard Shortcuts" before, and it seemed to deal with shortcuts on a system-wide basis. I want to specifically modify menu-item shortcut-keys (accelerators) ... and if possible, add my own menu-items.