# Gedit has an unlisted Ctrl-D shortcut which deletes a line. How can I override it?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

In Gedit, I installed the [line_tools](http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/LineToolsPlugin) plugin. It uses Ctrl+D to duplicate the the current line. When I pressed Ctrl+D, it did the opposite! It deleted the line instead!

It turns out that Gedit has an **unlisted** *(not in the menu)* shortcut-key: Ctrl+D, which deletes a line.

It is quite simple to change *any* menu item's shortcut-key in Gedit by enabling [Editable Menu Accelerators](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5241/ubuntu-editable-menu-accelerators-on-a-per-app-basis-where-is-this-option), but I can't change this  *delete-line* action's key, because there is no menu item for it!

How can I override this *delete-line* action?  .. and what other unlisted actions does Gedit have? .. and why is it (they?) unlisted?

PS: The developer of the 'line_tools' provides the plugin with Ctrl+D set to 'Duplicate'.. I assume he tested it; which would suggest that there was no such clash circa 2008-01-30 (the timestamp on the downloaded `line_tools.py`  )

Comment: Have you looked through GConf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a ***workaround*** for this particular `Ctrl+D` shortcut...

It was interesting to see that most on [the site where I found it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1384779) have been a Notepad++ users (me too :), where Ctrl+D was the "delete-line" shortcut...

The "fix" involves a simple mod to the 'gedit' binary... It changes one byte of a name, so that the shortcut reference becomes invalid...
This frees-up the Ctrl+D shortcut, and allows the plugin to function normally, and the new Ctrl+D menu-item is editable.

The only side-effect appears to be that a "Warning" is issued, which you can see if you start 'gedit' from the terminal...
Because this is a "hack" (in the roughest sense of the word), it is possible that there could be other side-effects, eg. maybe something doesn't get cleaned up properly... but I'll be using it...

Here is the 2-minute hack:
(The fix will need to be re-applied when gedit is updated)

```
# Make a backup of 'gedit' binary
sudo cp /usr/bin/gedit{,.before-ctrl+d-hack} 

# Hexedit the 'gedit' binary ...(I've used 'ghex2`)
gksu ghex2 /usr/bin/gedit

# In 'ghex2' 
#     Find the string: delete_from_cursor
#     Replace it with: #elete_from_cursor
#
# Save the binary, and exit... 
#
```

Comment: Even if that sound interesting, i don't know why you didn't install with Wine.  Anyway, i wanna hack gedit too to get rid of Ctrl+Destroyer shortkey. Thank you.

Comment: (The fix will need to be re-applied when gedit is updated) . Seems what you really like is the sed command from @Stephen Boesch

Answer (score 3):

I like the idea to do a binary edit. However the process described above seems too cumbersome.

Here is a much simpler and more reliable way:

```
sudo sed -i "s/delete_from_cursor/_elete_from_cursor/g" /usr/bin/gedit
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I cannot believe that works! Seems sed assumes the ascii conversion to the binary string comparison.  I've get confused by reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760717/hex-string-replacement-using-sed.