# Where to configure shortcut keys of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I would like to configure and change some shortcut keys of Nautilus (file manager of Ubuntu). Does anyone know where I could do that?

**Edit1:** Precisely, initial binding for "go to parent folder" in Nautilus is `Tab + Up arrow`, I would like to chang it to `Ctrl + Up arrow` because `Tab + Up arrow` has already been set to other things via `Compiz`.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/5241/ubuntu-editable-menu-accelerators-on-a-per-app-basis-where-is-this-option

Answer (score 6):

In Ubuntu 13.04  through 16.04 at least, the keyboard shortcuts for Nautilus are mapped in the "~/.config/nautilus/accels" file.  Edit that file to change the mappings.

Comment: In the later versions:  Nautilus 3.22 has no such file.

Answer (score 3):

[This Nautilus extension](https://github.com/vitaut/captain-nemo) allows you to edit keyboard shortcuts (accelerators).

After installing the extensions go to `Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts...` in the main menu and search for the `Up` action in the `Keyboard Shortcuts` dialog. Click the Key cell corresponding to this action and enter a shortcut:

[image]

Unlike the `can_change_accels` solution this will also work with Unity's global menus.

Answer (score 1):

I assume, you mean the keys for something that can be found in nautilus' menu bar.
First: This doesn't work if the global menu is on. Since you can't disable it for nautilus on a per-window basis (for nautilus is always running in the background), you should either log in to a non-unity-session (like gnome shell) or disable it for all windows. ([Here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/disable-appmenu-global-menu-in-ubuntu.html) is a guide how to disable it). You have to change a setting in gconf-editor (which might not yet be installed on your system, but can be found in software center). The key you need to enable is:

```
/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels
```

Probably you need to log off and back on again to make this change take effect. Afterwards just point at the menu entry whose schortcut you want to change and press the desired keys. After all changes are done, you can turn on global menu again.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... I have updated my post... Actually, what I want to change ("go to parent folder", "go previous", "go forward"...) can not be found in the menu bar... Do you have any idea?

Comment: On my system these functions can be found in the menu called "Gehe zu" (german - in english it's probably named "Go to"). You should therefore be able to change them.