# Ctrl+tab stoped working in gedit after installing xfce

Tags: 14.04, gnome, xfce, gedit

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 in virtualbox. I recently installed `xfce` and I have noticed that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> stopped working in `gedit` both in `xfce` and **GNOME**. It works fine in Firefox for example.

Is there anyway I could fix it? I already have taken all the basic steps (update, upgrade, restart).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should see this topic:

> [Custom keyboard shortcuts in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223986/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gedit)

However, you will discover many problem from your cross upgrade.
I recommend you for new installation.