# How to delete a line using a shortcut in Gedit?

Tags: gedit

Is there any shortcut for it?

If not is it possible to set a key for this operation?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Answer (score 5):

yes you can using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> as you can see in this page under the Shortcut keys for editing files: [Gedit shortcut keys](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Position the cursor anywhere on the line you wish to delete and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Apparently the shortcut is simply built-in into Gedit. I can't find an easy way to change it; apparently that's technically not possible [anymore], or at least [not easily](https://askubuntu.com/a/224018/380067).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look [here](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en)

It is `Delete the current line:` <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

For anything related to text in general:

Use <kbd>Home</kbd> to put the cursor at the beginning of the line then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>

Similarly you can set the cursor at the end using <kbd>End</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>