# Disable XFCE's ctrl+W to close window?

Tags: shortcut-keys, xfce

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> works for all windows as usual, but I find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> only works for some programs, for example, the file manager, any xfce settings program, mousepad, and the screenshot tools, however it doesn't work for any other programs e.g. calculator, terminal, everything else.

This is an inconsistent behavior, and I'd like to disable this as I'd want <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> only function as shortcut to close my browser tab.

I have take a look on the [Window Manager](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/preferences), but sure enough there is **no <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> mentioned, anywhere**.

Comment: I think you will be able to disable it individually. To change gedit Ctrl+W shortcut, [we need to do this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223986/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gedit), but as it envolves gtk, it may reflect to other programs. But, it's on gnome. I don't know about XFCE.

Comment: It's not in the window manager because this shortcut is used by applications themselves. I usually find ctrl+w anoying because it's the save shortcut in `nano`.

Comment: jesus, it took me months to figure out why my code editor closes on ctrl+W although the shortcuts are adjusted...

Answer (score 3):

Go to Keyboard shortcuts add custom shortcut "Do nothing" write `echo` as command.
And bind it to Ctrl+w. It worked for me.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation but `echo` and bind to `Ctrl+w` doesn't seem to work, since `Ctrl+w` will close the binding window.

Comment: @Terry You can ask a new question about it.

Comment: Seems to work for me too, in gnome. BTW, you can also use `:` as a command which does literally nothing (where echo still attempts to do something).