# How to change keyboard shortcut in gedit on Ubuntu 20.04 (including how to find the command names/key codes etc.)

Tags: 20.04, shortcut-keys, gedit

How do I change the gedit keyboard shortcuts on Ubuntu 20.04. I have read the question and answers on [Custom keyboard shortcuts in gedit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223986/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gedit) but it seems all of it is outdated and no longer offers a solution (please correct me if I am wrong). At this point I think it is best to open a new question for modern systems otherwise answers just get buried under the out dated ones. I would also appreciate if an answer includes how to construct new examples so if a method involves for example strings like `"(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/GeditWindowActions/SearchFindPrevious" "<Shift>F3")"` it would be great if it is clear where to find the names of commands such as *"SearchFindPrevious"*.

Specifically I would like to remove `Alt+ArrowKeys`.