# Conflicting shortcuts in Unity

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, filemanager

I'm used from Windows to press alt+up to navigate to the parent folder in the file explorer. When I do this in the Unity file manager, it moves up but it also opens the HUD, stealing focus from the file manager. Is there a different shortcut for the navigation or another workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> a little bit longer there will not be any conflict.

As alternative, you can:

1. Change the HUD's use of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key:

   - [How do I modify or disable the HUD's use of the Alt key?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/122209/how-do-i-modify-or-disable-the-huds-use-of-the-alt-key)
2. Change shortcut keys for Nautilus:

   - [Where to configure shortcut keys of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69324/where-to-configure-shortcut-keys-of-nautilus)