# Replicating or remapping Ctrl-L keyboard shortcut behavior (focus path/address bar) in Nautilus file browser

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, nautilus, gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome

I've recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and am working to get used to it. Coming from other environments, (possibly including the Unity GUI shell before it was retired from being the default) I'm very used to <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to move the cursor into the location-bar to jump to paths I can type directly. The current Nautilus (3.26.4) doesn't have an obvious way to enable this binding.

Though I have no reason to remove the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut, I'm looking for a way to have <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> do the same thing, as I find it more natural to hit. Ideally, this could be done without replacing Nautilus, though I'm flexible if the answer would be "modify X, download a ton of dev-packages, and then recompile from source."

***So***, without having to abandon the (now-default) GNOME GUI shell, how can I do this?

---

Footnotes: I'm aware of the existing <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd> shortcuts to begin typing paths from the root and home directories, but sometimes I want to modify the current path, rather than wipe it out, as those two do.

Sorry if this is a dumb question; I'm swimming here because it seems Canonical has moved and in some cases **re**moved Nautilus options between practically all major versions.

I've already tried using `dconf-editor /org/gnome/desktop/interface/can-change-accels` to allow editing `~/.config/nautilus/accels` in order to change the line starting with `; (gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Enter Location"` but apparently ~/.config/nautilus/accels [is not honored](https://askubuntu.com/a/680053/432173) anymore anyway.

Also from what I understand I don't think it will help to do anything with `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0`, since I believe there must be a GUI option to hover before a binding can be set.

References:

- [Editing Nautilus shortcut keys 13.04 through 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69324/where-to-configure-shortcut-keys-of-nautilus)
- [No shortcuts file appears after Nautilus 3.22+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69324/where-to-configure-shortcut-keys-of-nautilus#comment1402650_325758) (?)
- [Captain Nemo](https://github.com/vitaut-archive/captain-nemo), which allowed editing shortcuts, is no longer supported due to removal of key Nautilus features (last update mid 2013)
- RobotMan/Devim [adds a way to bind shortcuts to scripts](https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/432173) in Nautilus!