# Assigning shortcuts (accelerators) to Nautilus 3

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I want to assign some shortcuts to menu actions in Nautilus 3.2.1 running under Ubuntu 11.10.
I followed the steps shown here [How do you create a "new document" keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53202/how-do-you-create-a-new-document-keyboard-shortcut) but it did not work for me. Switched to gnome classic so I can get the normal menu, hovered over the desired action pressed the desired keys but nothing happened (restarted nautilus, re-logged and nothing).

Any suggestions or ideas on how to assign custom shortcuts to actions in Nautilus 3

Comment: It works for me..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is nearly the same as the answer in the question you linked to, except you need to use `dconf-editor` instead of `gconf-editor`. I had to install `dconf-editor`, which if I remember correctly, comes with the `dconf-tools` package. Also, the `killall nautilus ...` command did not appear to be necessary.

So, once you've got `dconf-editor`, run it.

1. Go to `org/gnome/desktop/interface`.
2. Check the box for `can-change-accels`.
3. Open Nautilus and highlight the menu item whose key binding you want to change, either with your mouse or via the keyboard, and press the key(s) you want to use as the shortcut.
4. Don't forget to *uncheck* `can-change-accels` in `dconf-editor` after you're done.

Comment: Does not work on 14.04 LTS.

Comment: This solution works on 14.04: http://askubuntu.com/a/288403/59600 .

Answer (score 3):

I use a little extended workaround.

1. Open `dconf-editor`. Find `org` > `gnome` > `desktop` > `interface` and check `can-change-accels` option.
2. Open `~/.gnome2/accels/` folder. Here you should see a file named `nautilus`. It contains all available nautilus actions you can assign an accel to.
3. Edit this file, save and close.

   eg: I transformed the following line

   ```
   ;&nbsp;(gtk_accel_path "&lt;Actions&gt;/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "")
   ```

   into

   ```
   (gtk_accel_path "&lt;Actions&gt;/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "&lt;Alt&gt;t")
   ```

   and now I am able to open terminal in current directory by pressing `<Alt>t`.
4. Uncheck `can-change-accels`.
5. Restart nautilus.

   ```
   pkill nautilus && nautilus
   ```

Comment: Modifying `~/.gnome2/accels/` works for me without having to set `can-change-accels` first.

Answer (score 2):

> It's due to the presence of the global menu?

Yes. You can set the keys by launching apps without global menu `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0 gedit`

Once set, it will work with the global menu.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this answer, ["Another way to define arbitrary hot keys"](https://askubuntu.com/a/87118/61876) .

I downloaded that python script from [here(git repo)](https://github.com/vitaut/captain-nemo) and changed the keyboard settings to my liking (I don't like overriding <kbd>F6</kbd> , <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> as the author has done in his proof of concept).

This is the only thing that is working for me in Nautilus, as far as changing/adding keyboard shortcuts is concerned. dconf-editor or gconf-editor change accel just doesn't work.

I am on Ubuntu Unity and not using Gnome Classic etc, and I hope you too are on the same boat. Of course, I have installed a bunch of stuff on top of that ( [protoiyer.github.com "Setting up my linux box and ruby on rails"](http://protoiyer.github.com/blog/2012/05/02/setting-up-my-linux-box-and-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-12-dot-04-edition/) ) to tweak Ubuntu/Unity, and so not sure whether any of it is screwing up with the dconf-editor setting.

It would be great if we can understand why it is working for @wim :).

Comment: I can't comment under user55822's reply (may be since I am a new member to this community), hence replying here:
I tried with global menu disabled and it allowed me to set new shortcuts, and I was happy for a few moments. When I closed the nautilus window and then restarted it (nautilus -q && nautilus) I find that all my newly baked in shortcuts are gone. Looks like the shortcuts you set are not persisted when you go back to use global menu. I am now back to using my python script.

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.15 it is not possible to use the accel file anymore, but it is possible to rebind keys by utilizing python-nautilus. Similar to an answer above I use a python script to rebind the keys.

Here is a good explanation of how to do it. If the folder and file don't exist, you can simply create them and it works just fine.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Tips_and_tricks#Modify_Nautilus_Hotkeys

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

[This extension](https://github.com/vitaut/captain-nemo) allows you to assign keyboard shortcuts (accelerators) to various menu actions:

[image]