# Cannot set custom shortcut using can-change-accels in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus, shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning shortcuts (accelerators) to Nautilus 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3)

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and enabled in `dconf` -> `org`->`gnome`->`desktop`->`interface` and enabled `can-change-accels`. But it doesn't seem to work. It is the option to set a custom shorcut for actions in the menu).

Is it due to the presence of the global menu? How to solve?