# Change menu item shortcut key like I used to be able to

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, shortcuts

In 10.04 I had my system set up so that I could hover my mouse over a menu item and type a shortcut and that would be the shortcut for that item. To do this I had enabled `/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels` in the gconf-editor.

However, after upgrading to 12.04 this seems to have disappeared. The item is still there in gconf but it seems to have to effect.

I would really like this to work because it is a really neat trick that make my life SO much easier.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you try http://askubuntu.com/questions/127174/can-change-accels-not-working-on-ubuntu-12-04-and-nautilus?

Comment: That seems to be hard coding a key to a specific action?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-appmenu/+bug/610234

I remapped my gedit keys by customizing my gtk-3 theme & the gedit "accels" file like so: https://live.gnome.org/action/login/Gedit/KeyboardShortcuts#line-102

Other gnome applications seem to have similar "accel" maps that they read on startup:
~/.config/banshee-1/gtk_accel_map

```
$ find .config -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l GtkAccelMap
.config/gedit/accels
.config/banshee-1/gtk_accel_map
.config/evince/accels
.config/eog/accels
.config/Empathy/accels.txt
```

In case you're not using a key combo which already has a default mapping, it wouldn't be necessary to edit `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. Just edit the relevant `GtkAccelMap` file and restart the application.