# Ubuntu 12.10 create Empty document shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Assigning shortcuts (accelerators) to Nautilus 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3)

I have just learned how to assign shortcut to "create new empty document" in nautilus. I followed stevelove [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3)

Shortcut works well but only in nautilus.

Is there any possibility how to enable this shortcut on my Desktop?