# Shortcut keys to create Empty Text Document in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

In *Nautilus* there is a shortcut key to create a new folder witch is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. Is there such thing to create *Empty Text Document*?

Comment: See [Assigning shortcuts (accelerators) to Nautilus 3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3)

Comment: Thanks @jokerdino; So this was a duplicate? If yes, what should I do now? should I remove it?

Comment: This solutions is best: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194329/keyboard-shortcut-to-create-a-new-empty-file-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut to do that, sorry.

Comment: Please feel free to contribute to the bug report [770583](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=770583) on this topic.