# Keyboard shortcut to create a new empty file on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus

I was wondering whether there is a possibility to assign a keyboard shortcut for creating a new empty file in Ubuntu 18.04 for nautilus. Namely if there is a possibility to assign a keyboard shortcut to the "Empty File" option generated by the right mouse click. The solution provided [on this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/53205/349837) does not appear to work for Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You just want a shortcut to quickly create an empty file? Or do you want a keyboard shortcut that shows the New Documents menu? Can help you with the former, not with the latter.

Comment: I want a shortcut to quickly create an empty file. Thank you for the reply @vanadium

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nautilus unfortunately does not allow the user to assign keyboard shortcuts to functions, as in the old days. Still, there is a workaround to create your own hotkeys through the use of nautilus scripts, which can be assigned a hotkey.

You can create a shortcut key to quickly create an empty file as following.

**1) Create a nautilus script that does what you want**

*a) Create the scripts folder if it does not exist*

If the folder `scripts` does not yet exist in the folder `.local/share/nautilus/scripts`, then create it first. `.local` is a hidden folder in your home folder. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to toggle the display of hidden files in the file manager.

*b) Create a new script*

Then create a script file in the nautilus scripts folder with the following command.

```
gedit "/home/$USER/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/New Empty File"
```

You can leave `$USER`: it should normally automatically be substituted with your login name.

The script could look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp "/home/$USER/Templates/Empty Text Document.txt" .
```

Also this nautilus script will recognize the variable `$USER`. Alternatively, replace the variable by your own login name.

*c) Make the script executable*

Make the script file executable (Right-click, properties or `chmod +x "/home/$USER/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/New Empty File"`

**2. Testing the script**

Close Files fully and restart it. To make sure it is fully closed, use the command

```
killall nautilus
```

After restarting, you should have a new entry "New Empty File" in your right-click menu when a file is selected.

**Assign a hotkey to your script**

*Edit 2020-11-17* Unfortunately, this seems broken in Files 3.38.1 that comes with Ubuntu 20.10.

Creating a new file with the right-click menu is easy enough without the script. However, the reason we do this is to be able to assign a hotkey. For that, create a file `scripts-accels` under `.config/nautilus`

```
gedit /home/$USER/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels
```

Suppose we want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> as the shortcut key. Then, the file should contain at least the last line from the following snippet:

```
; Commented lines must have a space after the semicolon
; Examples of other key combinations:
; <Control>F12 Terminal
; <Alt>F12 Terminal
; <Shift>F12 Terminal
<Control><Shift>t New Empty File
```

*Bonus tip*

You can give your new menu entry in the Scripts menu an accelerator, by prepending the script name with `_`. The letter prepended by `_` will show up with an underscore. This way, a script named "_New Empty File" can be summoned from the keyboard as (a file must be selected) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>.

Comment: thank you @vanadium your solution works like a charm!

Comment: I have only 13 reputation so I cannot upvote the answer but I will mark it as solved! :)

Comment: Thank you. It would be better if one could assign keyboard shortcuts to any function, but unfortunately it does not work like that.

Comment: I don't know why but in Ubuntu 20.04 combinations with a letter such as t do not seem to work. The combinations with F12 do work.

Answer (score 1):

The solution [above](https://askubuntu.com/a/1194547/427200) is almost perfect. Unfortunately the script is copying a new empty file and it is overwriting the file in a given directory if one exists under the same name. This is potentially dangerous.

To overcome it the script should be:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp --backup=t "/home/$USER/Templates/newfile"  .
```