# Changing nautilus key

Tags: nautilus, 13.04

I cannot seem to find a way to set "up 1 folder" to backspace in 13.04 (Nautilus 3.6.3)

I tried editing `~/.config/nautilus/accels`
and I also tried the *dconf* > *org* > *gnome* > *interface* > *can change accels*

What are the steps to change this ?

Comment: I don't know how you can do this, but there is another shortcut available. `Alt+LeftArrow` can be used to go back, and `Alt+RightArrow` can be used to go forward.

Comment: I do not understand why would Ubuntu dev team remove such a feature in the first place! Poor decision.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the accel key to the config file. I did in a terminal console:

```
echo '(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "BackSpace")' >> ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

Restart nautilus after killing it by executing

```
nautilus -q
```

Extracted from:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1108637/comments/6

Comment: Does not work for Nautilus 3.16 (so Ubuntu 16.10 and later). for workaround for scripts, see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
edit ~/.config/nautilus/accels
```

Press Ctrl+F and type `Alt>Up` to find the right line.

Remove the `;` symbol in front of the line:

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ShellActions/Up" "<Alt>Up")
```

Change `<Alt>Up` to `BackSpace`

Comment: 16.04 In my case it is GoUpAccel instead of Up. Dont forget to restart nautilus -> nautilus -q. Also, setting /TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal to <Alt>T helps a lot when nautilus is in a list view.