# Keyboard shortcut for terminal in Ubuntu 16.10 not working

Tags: keyboard, nautilus, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal, 16.10

I had the shortcut for "open terminal here" working in 16.04 using

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal" "F12")
```

in the `~/.config/nautilus/accels`. After the update to 16.10 the shortcut stopped working.

Does anyone knows if the accelerator changed or if there is another way of setting it?

How can I debug the problem to figure it out?

Update: Tested this on another computer with 16.10 upgraded from 14.04 and it is not working either.

Comment: My guess is that the Gnome developers removed that feature from Nautilus between v3.18 and v3.20. They're notorious for the removal of features that they feel are used rarely and may be implemented through plug-ins. You could try [Nemo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nemo/), a fork of Nautilus, instead.

Comment: what are you exactly looking for? - a keyboard-shortcut (title) or a shortcut via right-clicking (post)?

Comment: In the old version it was in both. The shortcut via right-clicking is still there. But the accelerator to trigger it through keyboard is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by `David Foerster` Nautilus doesn't support the accel map anymore (currently I'm testing on Ubuntu 17.10).

I found the answer on https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/44054

Just a note, the script on `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts` must have no extension. If you put an extension it won't work (at least in my case it didn't). Also, remember to make it executable.

## Solution

(In case the link and the solution is broken)

So in my case it was a

```
echo "#! /bin/sh
gnome-terminal" > ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Terminal

chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Terminal
```

Then, I just created

```
echo "F12 Terminal" > ~/.config/nautilus/scripts-accels
```

Then, after restarting nautilus, the terminal is opened through that script by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.