# Can't set custom accels in 17.10 to 'Open in Terminal' as under 16.04

Tags: nautilus, 17.10, gnome-terminal

I tried to set a shortcut for the 'open in terminal' drop down option from nautilus as in the last distribution of ubuntu by adding:
; (gtk_accel_path "/ExtensionsMenuGroup/NautilusOpenTerminal::open_terminal" "F12 ") in the ~/.config/nautilus/accels
and looked up some previous solutions but none has worked out in the artful dist.

Does anyone know how to create custom nautilus shortcuts in ubuntu 17.10?
Thanks a lot for your help!

Best

Comment: Isn't "open in terminal" already there?

Comment: Yes it is but without shortcut! That's my question how to add a short cut for it?

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/696901/775359

Comment: Make sure you provide executable permissions to the `Terminal` script. `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Terminal`. See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1062263/775359