# How to change Nautilus shortcuts keys in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, 18.04

Changing `~/.config/nautilus/accels` doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried to change some existings shortcuts and set one for "Open in terminal".
Similar question:
[Can't set custom accels in 17.10 to 'Open in Terminal' as under 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012211/cant-set-custom-accels-in-17-10-to-open-in-terminal-as-under-16-04)

Comment: Take a look here as ~/.config/nautilus/accels is no longer used, https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16/696901#696901

Comment: Make sure you provide executable permissions to the `Terminal` script. `chmod +x ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/Terminal`. See here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1062263/775359