# Replace Gnome Terminal with Tilix in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, context-menu, keyboard-accelerators

I want to use Tilix instead of Gnome Terminal because Gnome Terminal has so many bugs that bother me and that just don't get fixed.

I already figured out that I can make Nautilus give me an option to open Tilix in the current location with this setting:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'tilix'
```

However, now Nautilus gives me both an option to open Tilix and to open Gnome Terminal in the current location:

[image]

In an SFTP location, it's even worse because now there are a local and a remote option for both:

[image]

How do I hide the redundant options?

More importantly: How do I make Nautilus open Tilix when I press F4. In the past, Nautilus opened a terminal when you pressed F4. This feature was apparently considered too useful and has therefore been removed. However, one can get it back by adding the line

```
(gtk_accel_path "<Actions>/ExtensionsMenuGroup/TerminalNautilus:OpenFolderLocal" "F4")
```

to `~/.config/nautilus/accels`.

That is, if you use Gnome Terminal. What do I have to enter to make Nautilus open Tilix in the current location when I press F4?

Comment: I found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/680016/keyboard-shortcut-for-open-terminal-nautilus-3-16

Comment: have you read https://gnunn1.github.io/tilix-web/manual/vteconfig/ ?