# Keyboard Shortcut for loading file into julia

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

I'd like to have a keyboard shortcut do the following:

I select a file in nautilus and press the key-combination, it opens a terminal window, starts julia in it and loads the file in the julia environment (i.e. `include("file.jl")`).

Is there an easy way to do this in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *really* easy way, but there are ways. Nautilus supports scripts by itself. You can write them, then store them in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/` and use them by rightclicking on the file(s) and select the script to use.
This is covered in more detail e.g. here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto

By using the environment-variables initialized by Nautilus..

```
NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
- newline-delimited paths for selected files (only if local) 
NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS
- newline-delimited URIs for selected files
```

..you can then do a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI
eval ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS##*/}

gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'julia -L ${NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS##*/}; exec bash'
```

where you change into the current directory, `eval` if something is selected at all and with `gnome-terminal -x` start a new shell with the continous-option `-c` and launch `Julia`. The `-L` flag imports a file into your Julia shell. the `##*/` takes everything from the string starting at the last `/`.

store the script in `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts/`, make sure to set the right privileges with `chmod +x yourScript.sh` and try running it by selecting a file in nautilus, rightclicking it and running the script.

for the keybinding check out [Changing nautilus key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287936/changing-nautilus-key?answertab=active#tab-top)

I hope this works for you,

Gewure