# Change keyboard shortcuts for Nautilus on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: shortcut-keys, nautilus, 20.04

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04, and I would like to change the tab switching shortcuts from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>PageUp</kbd>/<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to the more natural <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assigning shortcuts (accelerators) to Nautilus 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3) and for the sisde bookmarks: https://askubuntu.com/questions/79150/how-do-i-remove-places-entries-from-the-nautilus-sidebar

Comment: @MarkKirby First question you link is not relevant to the current one. You cannot change hotkeys this way anymore in GTK3 applications.

Comment: Please post one question at a time here. You may want to edit your question and remove the part on the side bar. There, the question linked by Mark Kirkby most probably still works, even it it is very old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you nowadays cannot define shortcut keys in Nautilus yourself without editing source code. In older versions, you could edit a [configuration file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88010/assigning-shortcuts-accelerators-to-nautilus-3).

Gnome developpers do not support using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch tabs:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1000

https://bugs.launchpad.net/hundredpapercuts/+bug/388508

Comment: that's super sad to hear :(